# spring-cloud-gateway webflux ProxyExchange returns 404

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I would like to create a simple proxy and aggregator server with spring-cloud-gateway. I am using dependency `spring-cloud-gateway-webflux` and ProxyExchange to do that. I start the app in localhost and launch it from a browser, however, it returns 404 not found.

If I use `spring-cloud-gateway-mvc` instead of `spring-cloud-gateway-webflux`, surprising the proxy works and I can browse stackoverflow in my localhost. But I still would like to find out why `spring-cloud-gateway-webflux` is not working.

Can anyone help to point out anything that I am missing?

controller:

```
@RestController
public class RouteController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/**", method={ RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<byte[]>> proxy(ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response, ProxyExchange<byte[]> proxy) throws Exception {
        String path = proxy.path("/");
        if (request.getMethodValue().startsWith("GET")) {
            return proxy.uri("https://stackoverflow.com/" + path).get();
        } else {
            return proxy.uri("https://stackoverflow.com/" + path).post();
        }
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8080
```

I tried with adding the following to application.yml but it doesn't work.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        ssl:
          useInsecureTrustManager: true
```

Comment: Those configuration properties only work for the standalone gateway, not these modules. Properties for these are prefixed with `spring.cloud.gateway.proxy`.

Comment: My guess is `RestTemplate` ignores ssl errors by default and `WebClient` does not. You could create a `ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver` bean and configure `WebClient` appropirately. See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/d6347be26169c4ab6dc299e00e945ee359128ce9/spring-cloud-gateway-webflux/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/webflux/config/ProxyResponseAutoConfiguration.java#L53-L63

Comment: @spencergibb do you mean I should set property spring.cloud.gateway.proxy.ssl.useInsecureTrustManager=true? I tried but it still does not work.

Comment: that property doesn't exist. To do what you want you need to duplicate the code I linked to.

Comment: Thanks @spencergibb. I added a `ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver` bean but that still doesn't work. The bean code is here (https://github.com/william726/proxy-exchange-demo/blob/proxy-response-auto-configuration/src/main/java/com/example/demo/configuration/ProxyResponseAutoConfiguration.java). I am not sure if I did anything wrong esp. the annotations.

Comment: On the other hand, I did a quick and naive test with a new `WebClient` to call API or site, not to use the `ProxyExchange` nor create a new `ProxyExchangeArgumentResolver` bean.
It works fine and it does not complain about https or ssl. It is kinda weird and seems the 404 is not related to `WebClient` configuration. Code is here https://github.com/william726/proxy-exchange-demo/blob/test-webclient/src/main/java/com/example/demo/controller/RouteController.java

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, it's the problem of http headers. Add the following code, then everything works for me.

```
proxy.sensitive(HttpHeaders.HOST)
```

It seems like ProxyExchange will pass down the http request header by default, and in the case of `WebClient`, there is no default http header.

Comment: I lost whole day until finally this solved a problem. Really frustrating. I am still not sure why it is like that. I had 2 different set ups, one existing project with a lot of SB dependences and clean one only with MVC Gateway. Clean one work without this set up, but existing one not, throwing 404, for the same URL using in both projects....